# GHCi 7.8.2 doesn't use language extensions from file

Tags: haskell, ghc

Here's some simple code that requires `-XRebindableSyntax`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax, NoImplicitPrelude #-}

import NumericPrelude
import qualified Algebra.Additive (C)
import qualified Algebra.Ring (C)

newtype Foo = Foo Int deriving (Show)

instance Algebra.Additive.C Foo where
    (Foo x) + (Foo y) = Foo (x+y)

instance Algebra.Ring.C Foo where
    fromInteger = Foo . fromInteger

f :: Foo -> Foo -> Foo
f x y = x + y

g = f 3 5
```

Here's my GHCi transcript:

```
> ghci Foo.hs
  GHCi, version 7.8.2
  ...
*Main> g
  Foo 8
*Main> f 3 5

  <interactive>:3:3:
    No instance for (GHC.Num.Num Foo) arising from the literal ‘3’
    In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘3’
    In the expression: f 3 5
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = f 3 5

 *Main> :set -XRebindableSyntax
 *Main> f 3 5
   Foo 8
```

I'm 95% sure that when I loaded a file with an extension prior to GHCi 7.8, I wouldn't have to reset that extension in GHCi. Is this documented somewhere, or is it a bug? Is there an easy workaround (for example, telling GHCi to always use `-XRebindableSyntax`, which I will usually need?)

Comment: AFAIK GHCi doesn't load extensions from whatever modules you load. This is consistent with importing a module, the extensions in that module are not imported as well.

Comment: I just checked in 7.6.3 and I got the same behavior as above. Not sure what I was recalling. Is there some way to enable this extension in GHCi by default?

Comment: You could put it in your .ghci file as `:set -XRebindableSyntax` on a line by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there an easy workaround (for example, telling GHCi to always use -XRebindableSyntax, which I will usually need?)

You can put a `.ghci` file in the same directory as your source files. Now if you start ghci from that directory, the `.ghci` file will be load and its content executed like the commands you type at the ghci prompt. In this case, you would put `:set -XRebindableSyntax` in there.

I think this is better than putting `:set -XRebindableSyntax` into the `.ghci` in your home directory because you might have other Haskell projects in other directories that need different extensions.

For more ideas what to put into project-specific ghci files, see [Neil Mitchell's blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.de/2010/01/using-ghci-files-to-run-projects.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can do this on a project-by-project basis, I can't really ask for much more!